# Runtime exec() doesn't run commands when filename has spaces

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am new to Java and trying to convert one of my project from C to Java in order to combine it with another Java program. I'm having difficulty to get correct result when I use Runtime.exec(). I have the following program segment and Java ignores to process the given command.

```
command1 = "mv output/tsk/dir1/metabolic\\ waste.txt output/converted/file16.txt";                                               
r2 = Runtime.getRuntime();
p2 = r2.exec(command1);
p2.waitFor();
```

The problem here is the filename "metabolic waste.txt". The same command work when there is no space. I know I have to use escape char for space and I do it. I'm working on Ubuntu btw.

I also tried using

`String[] command1 = new String[] {"mv output/tsk/dir1/metabolic\ waste.txt", "output/converted/file16.txt";`

but it didn't work.

p.s. the given code is just an example. I don't only use linux mv command. I also run some of the command line tools such as pdf2txt. I still have the same problem of running commands if there is any space in the filename.

SOLVED: I've solved my problem. It's ridiculous that I had to remove escape character and use string array. So, NO ESCAPE CHARACTER for space. The following code just worked for this example and for more general.

```
source_filepath = "output/tsk/dir1/metabolic waste.txt";
dest_filepath = "output/converted/file16.txt";
String[] str2= {"mv", source_filepath, dest_filepath};
r2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str2);
p2.waitFor();
```

Comment: Java has its own *portable* way of doing this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html

Comment: Did it just not work but still execute the command, or did it not compile?

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder`!

Comment: @clcto I don't only need it for mv command. But it's good to know that internal way of Java. Thanks.

Comment: @DirkyJerky There is no compilation error but I don't think it execute my command.

Comment: @fge I'll try ProcessBuilder, thanks.

Comment: @fge I tried ProcessBuilder but no help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the escape, or enclose the path in quotes:

```
String[] command1 = new String[] {"mv output/tsk/dir1/metabolic\\ waste.txt", "output/converted/file16.txt"};
String[] command1 = new String[] {"mv \"output/tsk/dir1/metabolic waste.txt\"", "output/converted/file16.txt"};
```

You have to use `\\` because java also uses `\` as an escape character, so `"\\"` really just contains one `\`

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo. I do use "\\ " whenever I found " " in the filename.

Comment: Second line without quotes has just worked fine. No escape character is needed. Thanks again.

Comment: What if the command is generated dynamically? I have no way of knowing where exactly the spaces would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the filename in double quotes as follows :

```
  String srcFile = "output/tsk/dir1/metabolic\\ waste.txt"
  command1 = "mv " + srcFile +" output/converted/file16.txt";
```

Comment: Can i ask you why you are not using the FIle API for doing this task ?

Comment: @Karakot This is just an example of my error. As suggested above, I could use simpler techniques but I actually run some command line tools. I just gave a simple example of my problem. For example, I have the same problem for running the following command:
filePath = "file\\ name\\ has\\ space.docx";
command1 = "docx2txt.sh " + filePath;
r2 = Runtime.getRuntime();
p2 = r2.exec(command1);
p2.waitFor();

Comment: So this output folder is inside the folder from where you are running this piece of code ?

Comment: Yes, it's. There is nothing wrong with the file path. I've tested the command1 on terminal it works perfectly fine. It doesn't work when pass it from my Java code.

Comment: I tried it too : I am getting the following error mv: target `output/converted/file16.txt' is not a directory

Comment: I think you need a clear example. For example, can you get the following code running assuming you have a file named "hello world.txt": 
'Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("cp /pathTo/hello\\ world.txt") /home/username/Desktop/'